# Snort pcap analysis with ET rules

Tags: snort

I am trying to detect malicious behavior in pcap by using snort and Emerging Threat open rules. Here is what I did:

- Installed snort 2.9.6.0
- Downloaded https://rules.emergingthreats.net/open/snort-2.9.0/emerging.rules.tar.gz and unpacked to /etc/snort/rules
- Added an import "include $RULE_PATH/emerging.conf" to snort.conf
- Uncommented all rules in emerging.conf

When I run snort via:

```
snort -r pcap -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

I do not see any alerts in the output. I know that the pcap includes malicious traffic there are matching rules. What is the missing piece here?

Comment: Show rules that predicted an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the trick is to add:

```
-A console
```

Comment: FWIW: this just changes the alert mode, writing the alerts to the console instead of to the configured alert file. Very likely the alerts were already triggered before, they just did not show up on the screen (but in the alert file).